# Why is the FormData not being sent to endpoint in Angular 8?

Tags: angular, forms, file, file-upload

I am trying to post an image (.png, .svg, .jpeg) to a files directory endpoint using Angular 8.

I worked through this [tutorial](https://w3path.com/new-angular-8-file-upload-or-image-upload/) and the post executes, but what gets sent up, is empty. What I find confusing is that when I log this.fileData in the console, I get the correct information to display, but it doesn't get sent up.

What am I doing wrong? I will show some code and the screenshot of the console to show what is happening.

**.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import { Config } from '../config';
import { ConfigService } from '../config.service';
import { environment } from '../environments/environments';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-settings',
  templateUrl: './settings.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./settings.component.scss']
})
export class SettingsComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

  fileData: File = null;
  previewUrl: any = null;
  selectedImage: File = null;

  constructor(private configService: ConfigService) { }

  fileProgress(fileInput: any) {
    this.fileData = <File>fileInput.target.files[0];
    this.preview();
  }

  preview(){
    var mimeType = this.fileData.type;
    if(mimeType.match(/image\/*/)==null){
      return;
    }
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(this.fileData);
    reader.onload = (_event) => {
      this.previewUrl = reader.result;
    }
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getConfig();
    this.imageUrl = environment.image_url;
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(){}

  uploadImage(){
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', this.fileData)
    console.log(this.fileData);
    this.configService.uploadImage({title: '', name: 'Image', data: formData})
    .subscribe(response => {
      console.log(response);
    })
  }
}
```

**.component.html**

```
<ng-container *ngIf="show_form['club_badge']">
  <input type="file" name="club_badge" (change)="fileProgress($event)" accept=".jpg,.svg,.png,.jpeg">
  <div class="image_preview" *ngIf="previewUrl">
     <img [src]="previewUrl | safe:'resourceUrl'">
  </div>
  <button class="update"(click)="uploadImage()">Upload</button>
</ng-container>
```

**console.log of response and click event**

[image: console log]

**network tab payload request**

[image: network tab payload request]

I can see that something gets registered in the file directory when the post request completes, but it is showing as an empty file type. If I use ngModel on the input, the file that goes up is plain/text. How do I get this File to post up? Can anyone spot anything I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Worked out why it wasn't working.

1. needed to convert file to base64 and then 2. explicitly define the name of the file to name.jpg or name.png

   uploadImage() {
       let file = this.fileData;
       let reader = new FileReader();
       reader.readAsDataURL(file);
       reader.onload = () => {
         let data = reader.result;
         console.log('file data', data);
         this.configService.uploadImage({ title: '', name: 'image.jpg', type: 'image/jpeg', data })
           .subscribe(response => {
             console.log(response);
           })
       }
       reader.onerror = (error) => {
         console.log('Error', error);
       }
     }